# Substitute function not replacing text

Tags: excel, substitution

I am trying to use the substitute function in Excel to change the `05` in the first column to `04` as follows:

```
06-05NG22D021 --------------- 04NG22D021
06-05NG22D021-KP01  ---------- 06-04NG22D021-KP01
06-05NG22D021-M01  ----------- 06-04NG22D021-M01
06-05NG22D021-MK01 ----------- 06-04NG22D021-MK01
```

The problem is that when I use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-05", "-04")
```

it does not change the text to what it is supposed to be, it only changes when I remove '-0' like this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "5", "4")
```

it works correctly. The thing is that I have to include the '-0' in the string to ensure that the right part of the text is changed.

Comment: I just tried your example and it works all fine!

Comment: Could it be that the text you are working with uses hyphen (-) instead of dash (–) or vice versa? It seems to work okay for me.

Comment: I copied and pasted the stuff from the browser too and it worked well. It seems there is a problem with text in the original cell because when I try to copy '-05' from it and paste it in the substitute formula the 5 is replaced by a space. I don't think it could be the dash-hyphen problem

Comment: @user2155645 try to apply `CLEAN` and `TRIM` functions to the original text: usually for the copy/paste cases from whatever place (esp. web) it removes "invisible" symbols.

Comment: Enter `=CODE(MID(A1,3,1))` in a cell to find the ASCII of the third character. If it shows 45, it's a hyphen and perhaps character 4 is invisible. Otherwise, try using `CHAR(n) & "05"` where n is the character found.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's because the cell or the column is locked.
Or also it can be the Format cells number category.

To unlock:
Right click on the cell or the column and in the "Format cells" window go to tab "Protection", uncheck "Locked" if checked.

To change format cells number category:
Right click on the cell or the column and in the "Format cells" window go to tab "Number", change category to "General" especially if "Text" is already selected.

Return to your cell and re-apply the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to bypass the issue with:

```
=REPLACE(A1,5,1,4)
```

(copied down to suit) where the second parameter is the 5th character in `A1` (which just happens to be `5`).

[REPLACE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php).

(Does not work for first row in your example however.)